# Is there a way not to format number in Jinja2 templates using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Jinja2 seems to be shortening number when used in template with Ansible, I have this in: role/x/vars/main.yml:
`var_a: 0.010101010101010101`

In role/x/templates/a.txt.j2: `my_var_a={{ var_a }}`

After running it, I get the number in **a.txt** shortened by two(missing 01 at the end):
`my_var_a=0.0101010101010101`

**Is there a way not to format it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem of Jinja but of the representation of floating point numbers in Python (and C).

I tried this in python:

```
>>> var_a= 0.010101010101010101
>>> print(var_a)
0.0101010101010101
```

So indeed the number is truncated. I advise you to read this explanation about [floating point arithmetic](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Another example that shows the limitations:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
```